# change key names dynamically with enumeration

Tags: key, jq

I want to parse the output of the command `ps -Ao comm,pmem --sort=-pmem | head -n 6` as a JSON with the use of jq.

My current one-liner is

`ps -Ao comm,pmem --sort=-pmem | head -n 6 | jq -sR '[sub("\n$";"") | splits("\n") | sub("^ +";"") | [splits(" +")]] | .[0] as $header | .[1:] | [.[] | [. as $x | range($header | length) | {"key": $header[.], "value": $x[.]}] | from_entries]'`

The output is fine, but the keys are simply the column names of the ps command. I want for each entry to have a dynamic name like COMMAND_1, COMMAND_2... %MEM_1, %MEM_2 etc

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Have another JSON object that would have columns header as key and desired names as values, possibly stored inside a file, load it with --argjson or --slurpfile, then address that map with your column header to get the relevant name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution can to numerate line with `nl`

And use the first column `0` to compute the key name .

```
 ps -Ao comm,pmem --sort=-pmem | head -n 6 | nl -s' '  -v0 | \
 jq -sR '[sub("\n$";"") | splits("\n") | sub("^ +";"") | [splits(" +")]] | .[0] \
        as $header | .[1:] | [.[] | [. as $x | \
        range( 1 ; ( $header | length ) ) |  \
        {"key": ($header[.]+"_"+($x[0]|tostring)) , "value": $x[.]} ] | from_entries ]'
```